Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
enter image description hereCannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'
I have tried up creating an react app,where I have enter all the basic information like npx create-react-app, then after installing all the packages, I have entered npm start so this error comes up?
So I need a solution to go further.

Please show commands and code that you are using

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

This command solved the issue for me:
npm install --save-dev ajv@^7


I face this issue
npm start
> frontend@0.1.0 start
> react-scripts start 
Cannot find module 'ajv/dist/compile/codegen'

type and run:
npm install ajv@latest ajv-keywords@latest

and then:
 npm start

